# In GameMaker, how to bounce object further with the Bounce action?

Tags: gml

I've set it up so that when my character collides with a wall, it bounces (non-precisely, if that matters). However, I'd like it to bounce further than it currently does, and I don't see an option to adjust it. How should this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some more information to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On collision, increase the velocity of the object.